# Cannot resolve an MVC model property

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC Index page inside a Category View.

I originally wanted to place a modal popup dialog on the same Index Page with buttons for every record in the list which would trigger an Ajax call to get the data and display the data in the modal popup.

What I found, for some reason, is that the properties inside the div do not resolve the "CategoryDescription" property. I also notice that even if I place the LabelFor, EditorFor, and ValidationMessageFor HTML helpers above, right below the DisplayNameFor, they don't resolve. If I change it to a DisplayNameFor, it resolves.

So, what I did, was simply route an Edit and Details in the table where it would execute the GET (via the corresponding Controller) for the appropriate Action that was clicked on. This way, The Edit.cshtml page has the model data to display in the same exact modal popup form which gets resolved. This methodology works fine.

I was just wondering though, why couldn't the model properties be resolved in the Index page within the popup form?

I'm placing the code here below. Note that the modal popup form has been taken out and resides in the Edit.cshtml page instead of the Index.cshtml page.

```
@model IEnumerable<YeagerTechDB.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryDescription)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Category", new { id = item.CategoryID })" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#categoryEditModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>Edit</a> 
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Category", new { id = item.CategoryID })" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#categoryDisplayModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>Details</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="categoryEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="categoryModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="categoryModal-label">Category Description</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSaveCategory">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your model is `IEnumerable<Category>`, so how can you have `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryDescription)`?  `IEnumerable` does not have a property called `CategoryDescription`.

Comment: Great catch Paul! Thanks for the notification:)